# Oracle SQL: Calculate value using previous row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table with two columns: Cur_value and  Difference

```
       Cur_value        Difference
(-3)       3    
(-2)       4    
(-1)       5    
(1)                        1
(2)                       -2
(3)                        3
(4)     
(5)     
(6)     
(7)
```

Now I want to caculate value of Cur_value from row (1) to row (7) so that

cur_value(t) = cur_value(t-3) + dif(t).

It means my result is:

```
           Value        Difference
(-3)           3    
(-2)           4    
(-1)           5    
(1)        3 + 1           1
(2)        4 - 2          -2
(3)        5 + 3           3
(4)    3 + 1 + 2           2
(5)    4 - 2 + 1           1
(6)    5 + 3 - 2          -2
(7) 3 + 1 + 2 - 1         -1
```

. 
My question is: how to do this action by single Oracle SQL statements?

Answer (score 7):

Note that database table don't have any intrinsic order. Assuming you have some id or other column you can use to define the rows' order, you could use the [`lag`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) function to get the t-3 record:

```
SELECT cur_value, 
       difference, 
       LAG(cur_value, 3, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) + difference AS new_cur_value
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide the rows into 3s and take cumulative sums.  Something like this:

```
  select t.*,
         (max(cur_value) + over (partition by grp) +
          sum(difference) over (partition by grp order by id)
         ) as value
  from (select t.*, mod(row_number() over (order by id) , 3) as grp
        from t
       ) t
```

The sub query divides the rows into the three groups.  The max function gets the curr value from the first row.  The second does the cumulative sum of the difference.